# clip an image with a polygon shape

Tags: html, css

The following code clips an image with a rectangular shape:

```
img {
   position: absolute;
   clip: rect(20px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

```
<img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140">
```

Is there a way to clip an image with a random polygon shape with various sides at different points.

Comment: If you don't care about IE8 you may use SVG: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 0):

From the MDN documentation on `clip`:

> Warning: This property is deprecated. Use clip-path instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip

You can use the `clip-path` property, which also supports variable paths defined as an PNG mask or SVG path.

```
.target {
    clip-path: url(resources.svg#c1);
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

There also was [a good HTML5Rocks article on CSS shapes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/) last week. It includes notes about the new CSS shape and clip properties and how to combine them to let text float into that shapes.